# mysql query speed optimization

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have the following which when run on its own is very quick, but when I am performing this for many `entity_id` the queries start to take longer and longer (the loop is a PHP foreach) for example this query only takes 0.078 but the same query on a different entity within the loop on takes upto 2.1 seconds, **the queries seem to get slower and slower the more entities I put in the loop. Why is this? and how can I improve/optimize the query?**

```
foreach($entity_ids as $entity_id) {
    SELECT COUNT(*) as prev, DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%Y%m%d') AS date_group 
    FROM articles_entities 
    WHERE entity_id = '$entity_id' 
    AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
    GROUP BY date_group

    // store result
}
```

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles_entities` (
  `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `article_id` (`article_id`),
  KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like you have an array of ID's, then want to pull records from your table (in a way controlled by your statement) where the ID field matches one of the array values.

Instead of using a LOOP in PHP to run multiple SQL statements, the best thing to do is build one master statement then use PHP to handle the results. You can accomplish this using the SQL [IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) statement:

```
    // where $entity_ids is an array eg 1,2,3,4,5

    $sql="SELECT entity_id AS 'alt_entity_id', COUNT(entity_id) as prev, DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%Y%m%d') AS 'date_group'  
    FROM articles_entities 
    WHERE entity_id IN ".implode(",",$entity_ids)." 
    AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
    GROUP BY date_group, entity_id";
    // you may wish to revese the group fields, as you require, you may also wish to change the count field to date_group, depending on what you wish to be counted
```

This will run the original query one time, for all the id values you have, grouped by both date AND the id value passed. You can then use PHP to filter out the results for the specific id from the returned resultset.

This is far more efficient than the overhead produced by looping the execution of a query.

Your returned resultset will look something like:

```
 entity_id | count(entity_id) | date_group
 ----------|------------------|------------
     1     |        3         | 2010-04-01
     1     |        3         | 2010-03-01
     1     |        3         | 2010-02-01
     2     |        2         | 2010-01-01
     2     |        2         | 2010-02-01
     3     |        1         | 2010-06-01
     4     |        2         | 2010-06-01
     4     |        2         | 2010-02-01
```

Comment: Only thing missing from answer was selecting , entity_id AS alt_entity_id as I could work out which entity each one was (note i couldn't select just entity_id as it gave incorrect results. (I also has to swap the groupings over. if you update your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you're getting the entity values for your loop, but executing this query within a loop will always be a big performance overhead. If you're getting the entity_ids from a previous SQL query, it might make more sense to refactor your SQL to join the initial query with the loop query so that you're returning all the data you need in a single SQL query.

Comment: Where does $entity_ids come from?

Comment: I have first selected articles from that same table that match a specific criteria (different date range), and returned of its entities

Comment: @Lizard - my point is that it should be possible to combine that first select with your looped select: if you post both queries (and any other relevant table structures), we might be able to formulate a single query that will mean you don't have to execute the series of queries in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Roughly how many entities are you dealing with?

Could you insert the required entites into a seperate table and do a join, rather than have multiple queries?

Answer (score 0):

Take all ids into an array, join it to form a string and use "where in"   to get the details in optimized way

```
$enitityIDS = array();
    foreach($entity_ids as $entity_id) {
       $enitityIDS[]=$entity_id;
    }
    $entityIDString = join(",",$enitityIDS);
```

then do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as prev, DATE_FORMAT(`created`, '%Y%m%d') AS date_group 
    FROM articles_entities 
    WHERE entity_id in (".$entityIDString.")
    AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
    GROUP BY date_group, entity_id
```

Optimal Way

Comment: dont forget you also need to group the query by the id field, otherwise the result of the IN clause are indistinguishable